# Exact sequence in example in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper resulting from the Cech-to-derived-functor spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Grothendieck gives in his Tohoku paper in example 3.8.3 an example for that $\check{\mathrm{H}}^{2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \neq \mathrm{H}^{2}(X,\mathcal{F})$. 
In the beginning he states that  there exisits an exact sequence

> $0 \longrightarrow \check{\mathrm{H}}^{2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow \mathrm{H}^{2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow \check{\mathrm{H}}^{1}(X, \mathcal{H}^{1}(\mathcal{F})) \longrightarrow 0$

which results from the Cech-to-derived functor spectral sequence $\check{\mathrm{H}}^{p}(X, \mathcal{H}^{q}(\mathcal{F})) \Rightarrow \mathrm{H}^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{F})$.

My question ist: Does this short exact sequence exist for an arbitrary topological space $X$ and a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ or just in his concrete example? In the example there is $X = \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{2}$, $Y = Y_{1} \cup Y_{2}$ the union of two irreducible closed subsets $Y_{1}, Y_{2}$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{Z}_{X \backslash Y} = j_{*}(\mathbb{Z}_{X}|_{X \backslash Y})$ where $j: X \backslash Y \hookrightarrow X$ denotes the open inclusion.

I have shown that in the general setting there exists an exact sequence $0 \longrightarrow \check{\mathrm{H}}^{2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow \mathrm{H}^{2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow \check{\mathrm{H}}^{1}(X, \mathcal{H}^{1}(\mathcal{F})) \longrightarrow \check{\mathrm{H}}^{3}(X,\mathcal{F})$, and would therefore assume that Grothendieck is already in the special case of the example.

Comment: www.mathoverflow.net

Comment: Thanks, I posted my question there!

Comment: If I see this correct, in the stacks project we get this for derived-functor-cohomology and not for Cech-cohomology. Why do these cohomologies agree for $p = 3$?

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was misleading. You are right it is not exactly clear as to why that should be the case in a general setting.

Comment: You might find this discussion useful: (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4214/equivalence-of-grothendieck-style-versus-cech-style-sheaf-cohomology)